# Stripe and redirects are causing errors on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, stripe-payments

I made a simple eCommerce site using Rails and the Stripe API for payments.  When I uploaded it to Heroku, I had two strange problems that do not appear in local.

When I click on the purchase button, it is then supposed to go to a payment page like so:

http://localhost:3000/orders/9/payments/new

On this payment page you click on the Pay button, which takes you to the Stripe page.

However, on Heroku it simply redirects to /orders, which gives me an error.  If I brute force it by putting in the order number (for example, website.com/orders/1/payments/new) I can see the Payment page, but when I click on Pay, it does not redirect to Stripe.

Here is my Orders controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  order  = Order.create!(product: product, product_sku: product.sku, amount: product.price, state: 'pending', user: current_user)

  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [{
      name: product.sku,
      images: [product.photo_url],
      amount: product.price_cents,
      currency: 'usd',
      quantity: 1
    }],
    success_url: order_url(order),
    cancel_url: order_url(order)
  )

  order.update(checkout_session_id: session.id)
  redirect_to new_order_payment_path(order)
  end

  def show
    @order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

On the Payments#New page, here is the code I am using to redirect to Stripe:

```
<button id="pay" class="btn btn-card">Pay</button>

      <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
      <script>
        const paymentButton = document.getElementById('pay');
        paymentButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const stripe = Stripe('<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>');
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: '<%= @order.checkout_session_id %>'
          });
        });
      </script>
```

I am not sure why the error since I didn't define anything specifically for local.  Do I need to change something in my .env file?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I ran the heroku logs, I got an error saying "Stripe::AuthenticationError (No API key provided."  I already set API keys via the stripe.rb and they work on local, I am not sure why it is not reading it.

Comment: Have you set the API key as an env variable in Settings -> Reveal Config Vars in heroku?

Comment: I don't fully understand the flow here. If I remember my Rails the new helper will route to the create action. Also as the button is wired here, it should redirect to checkout when clicked not go to a new route in your backend. Also it neesd an event.preventDefault() which is also an issue. The event should be passed to the listenener handler.

Comment: I fixed it using NiftyAsp's suggestions.  I just copied over my variable name and API key by going to my app, Settings > Reveal Config Vars and then inputting them.  Nothing actually needed to be changed in the code.  Thanks!